# Return only the top N values after grouping by 2 columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I need to return the top n values of a data set after grouping by 2 columns. From another question I got answered I was able to count the values

```
#creating a random dataframe
dctf =  {"A":["First","First","First","First","First","First","Second","Second","Second","Second","Second","Third","Third","Third","Third","Third"],
      "B":["one","two","one","two","one","two","one","two","three","one","two","three","three","one","two","three"],
      "C":["Apple","Orange","Leaf","foo","Leaf","Apple","foo","Leaf","Apple","Apple","Orange","Orange","Orange","foo","foo","Leaf"]
      }
df_ex = pd.DataFrame(dctf)

#answer
df_ex['counts']=df_ex.groupby(["A","B"])["C"].transform('nunique')
```

I then used

```
df_ex = df_ex.groupby(["A","B"], as_index=False)['counts'].max()
```

which returned the following

```
    A   B   counts
0   First   one 2
1   First   two 3
2   Second  one 2
3   Second  three   1
4   Second  two 2
5   Third   one 1
6   Third   three   2
7   Third   two 1
```

I am trying to figure out how to only return the max values of the counts in each group. In this case just the max but also how I could return the top 5 for each group. For this example I would want it to return something like:

```
    A   B   counts
1   First   two 3
2   Second  one 2
4   Second  two 2
6   Third   three   2
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can try the following. Note that you will need `Pandas 2.0.0` for this to work as it uses [pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html). Also, based on your last output in your question, I am guessing you only want to group on column `A` and not `A` and `B`

```
# set n to the number of max values you want
n = 1

# # # you did this already
df_ex['counts'] = df_ex.groupby(["A","B"])["C"].transform('nunique')
# let's groupby again but this time get the nlargest
new = df_ex.groupby(["A","B"])['counts'].nlargest(n).reset_index(level=[0,1])
# based on the sample output I am assuming you only want to group on A here
# I added the merge so you can see the C column values
new[new['counts'] == new.groupby(['A'])['counts'].transform(max)].merge(df_ex['C'], left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

### n=1

```
         A      B  counts       C
1    First    two       3  Orange
6   Second    one       2     foo
7   Second    two       2    Leaf
11   Third  three       2  Orange
```

### n=2

```
         A      B  counts       C
1    First    two       3  Orange
3    First    two       3     foo
6   Second    one       2     foo
9   Second    one       2   Apple
7   Second    two       2    Leaf
10  Second    two       2  Orange
11   Third  three       2  Orange
12   Third  three       2  Orange
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out a way in python 3 if anyone is interested

after using the function below:

```
df2=df.groupby(["A","B"],as_index=False)['counts'].max()
```

I ranked the values by group A and filtered out the n number of ranks I desired and then sorted the values

```
df2['rank'] = df2.groupby(["A"])['counts'].rank(ascending=False)
df2=df2[(df2['rank'] < n)]
df2.sort_values('rank')
```